# GWT RPC and data translating to GXT Grid

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gxt

I am trying to translate data from server to client (GXT Grid).
On the server side I have a List with data and its ok.
Then I implement RPC methods and suppose that its ok too. Here is code:

1. GWTService

   ```
   @RemoteServiceRelativePath("gwtservice")
   public interface GWTService extends RemoteService {
       public List<WebasystProductData> getWebasystProductData();
   }
   ```
2. GWTServiceAsynch

   ```
   public interface GWTServiceAsync {
       public void getWebasystProductData(AsyncCallback<List<WebasystProductData>> callback);
   }
   ```
3. GWTServiceImpl

   ```
   public class GWTServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GWTService {

       //private Map<String, WebasystProductData> productData;
       public List<WebasystProductData> getWebasystProductData() {

       WebasystConnection waConn = new WebasystConnection();
       List<WebasystProductData> waPD = waConn.getWebasystProductData();

       return waPD;
   }
   ```

Then I implement proxy using my beanmodel, beanmodelreader, listloader, listore and grid.

```
...

rpc = RpcInit.initRpc();

RpcProxy<BeanModel> proxy = new RpcProxy<BeanModel>() {

    @Override
    public void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback callback) {
        rpc.getWebasystProductData(callback);
    }
};

BeanModelReader reader = new BeanModelReader();
BaseListLoader loader = new BaseListLoader(proxy, reader);
ListStore<BeanModel> store = new ListStore<BeanModel>(loader);

List<ColumnConfig> col = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("productIdWA");
column.setHeader("ProductID");
column.setWidth(50);
col.add(column);

column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("productNameWA");
column.setHeader("productName");
column.setWidth(120);
col.add(column);

column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("productPriceWA");
column.setHeader("productPrice");
column.setWidth(80);
col.add(column);

column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("categoryIdWA");
column.setHeader("categoryID");
column.setWidth(80);
column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
col.add(column);
```

When start my app - no data inside grid. Dont know whats the problem, no errors...
Suppose the problem is in client code

Comment: Are you sur WebasystProductData is a Serializable class ? What is the implementation of the List returned by waConn.getWebasystProductData(); ?

Answer (score 0):

The Grid doesn't do an initial laod by its self. Did you call com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.Loader#load ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RpcProxy<List<WebasystProductData>> proxy= new RpcProxy<List<WebasystProductData>>() {
        @Override
        protected void load(Object loadConfig,AsyncCallback<List<WebasystProductData>> callback) {

            getWebasystProductData(config,callback);
        }
    };
    BeanModelReader reader = new BeanModelReader();
    ListLoader<ListLoadResult<ModelData>> loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy, reader);
    ListStore<BeanModel> store = new LisStore<BeanModel>(loader);
```

then just:

```
Grid<BeanModel> grid = new Grid<BeanModel>(store,column);
    grid.addListener(Events.Attach, new Listener<GridEvent<BeanModel>>() {  
        public void handleEvent(GridEvent<BeanModel> be) {  
            loader.load();
        }  
      });
```

Remember that your Pojo  need to implements the BeanModelTag interface

and the

```
column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("XXX");
```

XXX need to be the same as your Pojo properties